# Active model serializer stops working suddenly on production after a deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

I have a Rails 6 app with Active model serializer. There are a few serializers defined for outputing result in a defined custom json format. I use AWS ECS containers to deploy the code to production. The default production configuration uses the out of box file storage for cache with all default production settings.

I noticed recently when I add columns to the table via the migration or add attributes to the serializer class. Some time after the deployment, the app does not output the object in the defined format with the serializer class. Instead, it just outputs the object as it is in the plan json with all attributes. This caused the web frontend to break as it expected the result to have the object root attribute and the custom format. It seems the serializer classes stops working and completely ignores the serialization. I have to do another deployment with the exact same code to fix this issue so it serializes the object properly.

There are 2 instances in ECS. I noticed when this issue happens, it returns the proper format intermittently so I guess it might have hit the good instance but the result is inconsistent. I also tried pulling the docker images from ECR and run them locally and they seem to be ok with all the code in place. For the deployment, there is a new container running just for the migration before the new code was deployed.

I am new to Rails application. I don't know what has caused this issue and how I can prevent this from happening. Maybe I need to use a centralised cache storage like Redis instead of local file system in each container. Anyone has experienced this issue? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you have a deployment issue.

Comment: Yeah, but I am not sure how to prevent this from happening or it has something to do with using local file cache. I am changing the cache store to use Redis but not sure if that will fix it.

Comment: Never mind. It turned out containers just simply run out of memory when there are traffic spikes. Increasing the memory solved this issue. It is good to know.